# Testing onLayout in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a component that uses the onLayout event using @testing-library/react-native, with the component using a setState function through the components props but the function is never called:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: 100

Number of calls: 0
```

How can I make this work? What is wrong?

Component:

```
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode
  setHeaderHeight: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>
}

const HeaderSetHeightWrapper = ({ children, setHeaderHeight }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper
      onLayout={({
        nativeEvent: {
          layout: { height }
        }
      }) => {
        setHeaderHeight(Math.floor(height))
      }}
      testID="header-h"
    >
      {children}
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

const Wrapper = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
`
```

Test:

```
it('should set the header height on layout', async () => {
  const mockHeight = 100

  const setHeaderHeight = jest.fn()

  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <HeaderSetHeightWrapper setHeaderHeight={setHeaderHeight}>
      <View style={{ width: 100, height: mockHeight }} />
    </HeaderSetHeightWrapper>
  )

  const wrapper = getByTestId('header-h')

  fireEvent(wrapper, new NativeTestEvent('onLayout', { nativeEvent: { layout: { height: mockHeight } } }))

  await wait(() => expect(setHeaderHeight).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockHeight))
})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@testing-library/react-native` has a `fireEvent.layout` trigger now, at least as of v5.0.3:

```js
import { render, act, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react-native';

test(() => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<MyComponent />);
  const view = getByTestId('my-view');
  act(() => {
    fireEvent.layout(view, {
      nativeEvent: {
        layout: {
          width: 300,
          // etc
        },
      },
    });
  });
});
```

This should trigger the `onLayout` event handler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is the further documentation that lists React Native events that could be fired?

Comment: Are you referring to the `nativeEvent` parameter? That is what a real layout event would contain so I'm replicating that.

Comment: A gotcha I've come across is that `fireEvent.layout` doesn't seem to fire the `onLayout` for `TouchableOpacity` elements, it does work for `View` though.

Comment: hmm, I must be doing something wrong, I'm on version `8` and it can't find `layout`: `_reactNative.fireEvent.layout is not a function`

Comment: `layout` does not seem to be an event in the latest versions of the library. Anyone else ran into this same issue?

Comment: I was able to remove the act and use the function directly -
`fireEvent(flatList, 'onLayout', { nativeEvent: {layout: {width: 500}}});`

Comment: Like previous but I changed function to `fireEvent.press` so act(() => {
      fireEvent.press(getByTestId(YOUR_TESTID), 'onLayout', { nativeEvent: { layout: { width: 500 } } })
    })

Answer (score 12):

You can use `fireEvent(element, eventName, data)`, its documentation is [here](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api#fireevent), and its type is:

```js
type FireEventFunction = (
  element: ReactTestInstance,
  eventName: string,
  ...data: Array<any>
) => void;
```

So, to fire `onLayout`, use the `layout` event name:

```js
// You can use any getBy* or another selector that returns a ReactTestInstance
fireEvent(getByText('Some label'), 'layout', {
  nativeEvent: { layout: { height: 100 } },  // The event data you need
});
```

Comment: This answer is what seems to work with the latest version (11.0.0) 

Answer (score -3):

```
wrapper.find('Wrapper').simulate('layout')
```

Comment: This question is asking about using `@testing-library/react-native`, not Enzyme.